Rudin's RCA Theorem 7.21
Theorem 7.21 states: If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at every point of $[a,b]$ and $f'\in L^1$ on $[a,b]$, then $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(t)dt$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.
From a very early theorem, we get this lower semicontinuous $g$ on $[a,b]$ such that $g>f'$ and $\int_a^b g(t)dt < \int_a^b f'(t)dt + \varepsilon$. Then for any $\eta>0$, Rudin defines the function
$$F_\eta(x)=\int_a^x g(t)dt-f(x)+f(a)+\eta(x-a)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (a\le x\le b)$$
and later uses the fact that $F_\eta$ is continuous. I know the "$-f(x)+f(a)+\eta(x-a)$" part is continuous. I know if $g$ were continuous, it would be bounded on $[a,b]$, and this would imply the rest of the continuity. But since $g$ is only lower semicontinuous ($\lbrace x:g(x)>\alpha\rbrace$ is open $\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$), I don't see how to get the continuity of $\int_a^x g(t)dt$.

Isn't $\int_a^xu(t);dt$ always continuous if $u$  is integrable?

Fair enough, but why is a lower semicontinuous function on [a,b] also integrable on [a,b]? I know it will have a minimum value somewhere in the interval, but I only know $g>f'\in L^1$, so I'm not sure why $g\in L^1$.

So I'm not sure that it is even true in general that if $g$ is lower semicontinuous on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^x g(t)dt$ is continuous. As a counterexample, on $[-1,1]$ we could take the function $g(t)=0$ for $t\in[-1,0]$ and $g(t)=1/t$ for $t\in(0,1]$. This function is LSC and not in $L^1[-1,1]$, and if we let $f(x):=\int_{-1}^x g(t)dt$, then $f(0)=0$ but $f(r)=\infty$ for any $r>0$, so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.
So going back to my original question, the fact that $\int_a^x g(t)dt$ is continuous uses more information from the context of the proof. If we can show that $g\in L^1[a,b]$, then continuity follows (thanks for the reminder, @MPW). In general, LSC functions are not necessarily in $L^1$, but in this case, Rudin obtains from Theorem 2.25 (Vitali-Caratheodory) a USC function $h$ (not mentioned in Rudin's proof of 7.21) and a LSC function $g$ such that $h\le f'\le g$ and $\int_a^b (g(t)-h(t))dt<\varepsilon$. This shows that $g-h\in L^1$, and since $0\le g-f'\le g-h$, then $g-f'\in L^1$ as well. Since $f'\in L^1$, the sum $g=(g-f')+f'\in L^1$, and we are done.

It seems that in Rudin's proof of Theorem 7.21, we actually don't need the continuity of $F_\eta$.
Rudin has proven that $F_\eta(t)>F_\eta(x)$ for sufficiently close $t>x$. Now $F_\eta(a)=0$ immediately implies $F_\eta(b)>0$, which is what we want.
